# Fragments ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть два фрагмента. В одном свой список, во втором - свой.
В первом сделан вызов контекстного меню, всё работает. Делаю подобное во втором фрагменте - вместо обработки кода из второго фрагмента делается вызов метода из второго фрагмента. Подозреваю, что дело в адаптере контекстного меню. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Фрагмент1:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_OPEN_ID, Menu.NONE, OPEN_TEXT);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, DELETE_TEXT);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_CONTEXT_OPEN_ID:
                openChar(t_prName, temp_chars.get(0), false);
                return true;
            case MENU_CONTEXT_DELETE_ID:
                showAlertOfDeleteDialog(info.position);
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Фрагмент 2:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_OPEN_ID, Menu.NONE, OPEN_TEXT);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, DELETE_TEXT);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info2 = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_CONTEXT_OPEN_ID:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"dfdfdfdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case MENU_CONTEXT_DELETE_ID:
                showAlertOfDeleteDialog(info2.position);
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено:
Нужно содержимое onContextItemSelected обернуть в условие c getUserVisivbleHint() для каждого фрагмента:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info2 = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case MENU_CONTEXT_OPEN_ID:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case MENU_CONTEXT_DELETE_ID:
                    //  showAlertOfDeleteDialog(info2.position);
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```